# Fetch class methods from an extended class from within a used Trait

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have a trait `AutomatedEmails` with a `submit` function, part of which features the below:

**AutomatedEmails.php (Trait):**

```
trait AutomatedEmails
{

/** Initial route function the form is posted to */
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $slug = $request->slug;

    // Fetch the action function required and load (from AutomatedEmailsController file)
    // The function must exactly match the slug in the automated_emails_actions table
    // with underscores rather than hyphens

    if (!method_exists($this, str_replace('-', '_', $slug)))
        return redirect()->to($request->redirectUrl)->with('danger', App::environment('local') ? 'Form processing function not set up for this form' : $liveProcessingError);


    // THE LINE ABOVE IS THE PROBLEM LINE - THE METHOD DOES NOT EXIST

}
```

I have a class which is also part of this package which contains form processing methods:

**AutomatedEmailsController.php:**

```
class AutomatedEmailsController extends Controller
{
    use AutomatedEmails;

    public $fillables = [];
    public $appends = [];
    public $tracking_data = [];
    public $action;
    public $thank_you = ['message' => 'Thank you - your enquiry has been received'];


    public function contact_enquiry(Request $request = null)
    {
      // method implementation
    }
}
```

I then want to create a class extension on the local project but make these methods available to the Trait (and this is where the the problem lies):

**AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension.php:**

```
class AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension extends AutomatedEmailsController
{
    use AutomatedEmails;

  public function vehicle_enquiry(Request $request = null)
     {
        // method implementation
     }
 }
```

**Here is the new form example:**

```
   <form method="post" name="vehicle_enquiry" action="{{route('automated-email', ['slug' => 'vehicle_enquiry'])}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="vehicle_id" value="{{$vehicle->id}}">
    <-- Additional inputs here -->
</form>
```

**And this is the route method in web.php:**

```
Route::post('/automated-enquiry', 'AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension@submit')->name('automated-email');
```

The purpose of this class is to add functions that pass through data about a new form that should be processed.

The problem is that the `vehicle_enquiry` method cannot be found on the **AutomatedEmails.php** Trait and therefore the form will not get processed as required.

What I am planning to do is suggest a file for the Trait to search for an instantiate methods from that file.

Comment: Is `$this` definitely an instance of `AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension`?

Comment: Hi Nigel, No it's an extension of `AutomatedEmailsController` which is also part of the package. The `AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension` is a local class that extends the package class, I then route the forms through to this class which all works OK until I try to access a new method

Comment: Unless it's an instance of the AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension class, then it won't know of any of the methods defined in the AutomatedEmailsController derived classes.

Comment: Is there any way to scan for extensions. I can do it this way but it means the exact extension filename will need to be searched for

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. It's actually both as I am using a trait with core functions for processing forms. The trait (part of a package) is used on the AutomatedEmailsController class  (also part of the package). In the local project I then create a AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension class which extends the AutomatedEmailsController. So the functions of the Trait will all be accessible by these classes. What I'm trying to do is access methods on the AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension from within the Trait which I realise isn't possible.

Comment: I am planning to create a function on the Trait which checks to see if the file exists then create an instance of it and use the methods available. Does this sound like the best solution?

Comment: You're absolutely right. The route file was cached and was skipping the extended controller `php artisan route:clear` ‍♂️Going to hang my head in shame. Thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time. Thought I was going mad as sure I had this working on a previous project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to refer to methods defined in composited classes from a trait (or from a parent class to methods on children classes).

See this, for example:

```
trait Foo {

    public function g($method = 'zbar') {
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            echo call_user_func([$this, $method]), "\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "we not good";
        }
    }
}

class Bar {
    use Foo;

    protected function zbar() {
        return 'abc';
    }
}

class SuperBar extends Bar {
    protected function xbar() {
        return 'edf';
    }
}

$a = new Bar();
$a->g('zbar');

$b = new SuperBar();
$b->g('xbar');
```

This outputs:

```
abc
edf
```

You can see it working [here](https://3v4l.org/Nsa7I).

In your case, it looks like your code is not going through `AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension` at all. To make sure, you can put a `die(class_name($this));` statement on `submit()`.

If you are not hitting that class, it could be because of Laravel's caching getting in the way. Clear cache and you will be good to go.

Additionally, since `AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension` extends on `AutomatedEmailsController`, there is no need to `use` the trait again. If it's used on the parent, the methods are already available on the children.

Comment: Thanks - see what you mean about the Trait not being required on the extension and that wasn't supposed to be left there. I can see exactly how your example works and that makes sense. The issue I'm facing is that `$this` refers to an instance of `AutomatedEmailsController` and not `AutomatedEmailsControllerExtension`. Why is that when I am routing through to the extended version?

Comment: This answer is the correct solution to the question and I have marked as such. The problem I encountered though was not due to anything incorrect in the code but instead unfortunately having cached the local routes for testing purposes the extended class was being skipped. `php artisan optimize:clear` to the rescue